# Intermediate values in haskell io

Tags: haskell, io

I am learning Haskell, and as an exercise I wrote a program that reads in an integer and prints the next one:

```
main = do
    line_with_n_in_it <- getLine
    putStrLn $ show $ (read line_with_n_in_it :: Int) + 1
```

However, it seems rather silly to me that I have to explicitly name the line that I read.

If I write

```
main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ (read getLine :: Int) + 1
```

`runghc` complains that `read` expects a `String`, but `getLine` provides an `IO String`. So from what I understand, it seems as though this magical `<-` operator converts `IO String` to `String`.

Is there a different operator or function that will let me simply inline the `<-` operator? So if `magic` were my magic function, I would be able to write my new program as

```
main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ (read $ magic getLine :: Int) + 1
```

Comment: `fmap (+1) readLn >>= print`

Comment: Or, `import Control.Applicative` to get magic `$`, aka `<$>`, giving `(+1) <$> getLine >>= print`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read about monads (and IO monad)

A good start [here](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html)

The problem is you must to "extract" the value from your monad and this is not "exactly" a function call.

Your first code is correct, you extract some value from monad

```
readedString <- getLine
```

and then, use it

```
putStrLn $ "Readed: " ++ readedString
```

you can avoid "naming line" but, in general, is fine write names for that.

to avoid naming, you must to write some monadic function and then bind

```
getLine >>= putStrLn . show . (+1) . read
```

but, again, I recommend to you read about monads (and IO monad).

By the way, the `<-` operator "is equal" to `>>=` operator, details [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation).

Comment: This might be a bit off topic -- but how come you don't need to annotate the type of `read`? Because it looks like `(+1)` can be applied to both `Float` and `Int`, so how does haskell know which to pick?

Comment: @math4tots: [Section 4.3.4  Ambiguous Types, and Defaults for Overloaded Numeric Operations](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html): *"Each defaultable variable is replaced by the first type in the default list that is an instance of all the ambiguous variable's classes.*. The defaults are `(Integer,Double)`, and since `Integer` is good enough for those operations, it gets used.

Comment: No simple response here :) Haskell only need know the final type when use it. On my last line Haskell use (by convention) `Integer` type (you get error if write `3.14`). But a "non final" function application is generic. Look the type of `(+1) . read :: (Num c, Read c) => String -> c`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Haskell explicitly *disallows* this behavior is precisely what makes it so valuable -- you can't mix pure and IO-riddled code.

The magical `<-` operator is syntactic sugar for monadic binding. For example, your original function can be rewritten explicitly with the `>>=` operator (pronounced "bind"):

```
main = do
  n <- getLine
  putStrLn $ show $ (read n :: Int) + 1

===

main = getLine >>= \n -> putStrLn $ show $ (read n :: Int) + 1
```

The fact that `<-` seems like magic to you is a good thing -- it's not standard haskell syntax, it's sugar. The latter way of writing the function should make more sense.

As for *why* this works, I can give you a handwavy explanation specific to the IO monad, and suggest that you read [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)'s chapters on monads (or the whole book, if you're real new!) to strengthen your understanding.

Here we go. `getLine` reads a `String` from `IO`, right? But this means that the result of the call is "tagged with IO"; it's a `String` wrapped in the `IO` context that we can't manipulate as we could a normal `String`. Doing such a thing would violate [referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29), since the `IO` context (i.e. what you're reading in) can change. Basically what that magic `<-` operator does is "pulls out" the pure `String` value from the `IO` context and allows you to operate on it. More explicitly, the `>>=` operator takes an `IO` action (`getLine`), and a function that takes a `String` to a new `IO` action (the lambda expression in the translated example), and returns that new `IO` action. This is a way of chaining `IO` expressions together, and "digging into" their inner values, operating on them, and re-wrapping them in `IO`. Monads in general are not something I (or anyone, for that matter) can explain to you in full detail in a SO answer, but I heavily suggest that you read LYAH if you intend to continue learning Haskell -- it's a great book and will get you up to speed quickly.